# How to show the JSON data dynamically when I click the particular user using onclick function in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I need help. Actually my task is, how to fetch that JSON data and show that data when I click the `{{client_management.name}}`.

It should show the JSON data of the client name, contact number, emailid (div) tag.

I mention my JSON below, please check that.

[image]

```
       HTML
       ----

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let client_management of dashboard_data?.account_mangement?.account_info?.account;let i=index">
                <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                <td>{{client_management.name}}</td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="client-label">Client Name: Client1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="client-label">Contact Person: Suresh</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="client-label">Contact Number: +91-9841252253 </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="client-label">Email ID: techsureshp@gmail.com </label>
            </div>
        </div>

    TS
    ---
      getManageDashboardDetails(){
        this.loaderService.display(true);

       const headers = new Headers({
       'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('Token'),
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      });
      const options = new RequestOptions({
       headers: headers
      });
         this.service.get(options, services.dashboard_service).subscribe((response) => {
         if (response.status === 200) {
             this.dashboard_data = response.json().dashboard_details;
             this.loaderService.display(false);
            }

          });
      }
JSON
-----
        "account_mangement": {
            "inactive_count": 0,
            "activate_request": 1,
            "account_info": {
                "account": [
                    {
                        "request": "vinodkumar",
                        "name": "vinodkumar",
                        "status": "active",
                        "info": {
                            "password": "xxx",
                            "address": "Chennai",
                            "additional_info": {
                                "date_time": "Fri Jun 22 13:26:40 IST 2018"
                            },
                            "name": "vinodkumar",
                            "mobile": "+919444999360",
                            "last_name": "R",
                            "designation": "Developer",
                            "org_name": "Volumata Analytics",
                            "first_name": "Vinodkumar",
                            "email": "vinodkumar.r@volumataanalytics.com"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "request": "sureshpillai",
                        "name": "sureshpillai",
                        "status": "active",
                        "info": {
                            "password": "yyyy",
                            "address": "Chennai",
                            "additional_info": {
                                "date_time": "Fri Jun 22 13:26:40 IST 2018"
                            },
                            "name": "sureshpillai",
                            "mobile": "+919044999360",
                            "last_name": "R",
                            "designation": "Developer",
                            "org_name": "Volumata Analytics",
                            "first_name": "sureshpillai",
                            "email": "sureshpillai.r@volumataanalytics.com"
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below steps :-

1) You can create two div's and by using some boolean variable, you can use structural directive *ngIf on the two div’s.

2) At ngOninit life cycle hook, provide data to both the div’s using any of the data- binding concepts of angular and only the first div will display.

3) When you will click on the client name, you should update the Boolean variable’s value and thus second div will display. Since the HTML inside second div is already binded to data, hence data will be already there.

4) You can add a class or Onclick event to the HTML element which is enclosing the Client name. In your case it is a td. And your whole logic for updating the value of Boolean variable will be written over here.

```
 <div> <span (click)="showDetails()">Client Name</span> </div>
 <div *ngIf="showClientdetails">
  <span>Client details </span>
 </div>

// Component.ts
  showDetails() {
    this.showClientdetails= true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click event to get which user is selected on that basis you need to fetch details like this -

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let client_management of dashboard_data?.account_mangement?.account_info?.account;let i=index" (click)='getDetails(client_management.name)'>
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{client_management.name}}</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">Client Name: {{selectedUser?.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">Contact Person: {{selectedUser?.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">Contact Number: {{selectedUser?.info?.mobile}} </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">Email ID: {{selectedUser?.info?.email}} </label>
    </div>
</div>

selectedUser = {};
getDetails(name) {
    let myJson = this.dashboard_data.account_mangement.account_info.account;

    myJson.map(obj => {
        if(obj.name == name) {
            this.selectedUser = obj;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

> component.ts

```
client:any;
```

> component.html

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let client_management of dashboard_data?.account_mangement?.account_info?.account;let i=index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td (click)="client=client_management">{{client_management.name}}</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>


<div *ngIf="client" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">{{client?.info?.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">{{client?.info?.email}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">{{client?.info?.mobile}} </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="client-label">{{client?.info?.org_name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```